# How to combine texture color and uniform color in fragment shader?

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, webgl, shader

I want to use one shader for both, coloured rectangles and/or rectangles which render textures. This is my approach:

```
precision mediump float;
uniform vec4 u_color;

uniform sampler2D u_image;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;

void main(void) {

vec4 texCol = texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord);

gl_FragColor = texCol * u_color;
}
```

But I get nothing. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Where's your `#version` directive?

Comment: This shader is used in webGL. I don't know if its necessary. If I leave out he "* u_color", the texture is rendered but a simple rectangle is black, although it should be green for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not have a valid texture specified for the sampler, the `texture2D` call will return transparent black — `vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)`. Multiplying by that value will always produce black again.

Instead of trying to use “no texture”, use a texture which has exactly one *pure white* texel. This will cause the multiplication to yield the `u_color`.

Or, you can simply switch between two shader programs, one for untextured geometry and one for textured geometry. Switching programs (`gl.useProgram`) is not very expensive.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to generate a pure white pixel once, so that I can reuse it everytime. I don't want to have a .png file in my workspace.

Comment: Yes, you can construct a texture from an array.

Comment: To add to what Kevin said, yes. `gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 1, 1, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, new Uint8Array([1,1,1,1]));`

Comment: That didn't worked out for me, so I used the gl.useProgram method with two different shaders. Thanks again!